# removing items from a generic List<t>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, list

I have the following method, I wish to remove items from my collection that match the product Id. Seems fairly straight forward, but i get an exception. Basically my collection is getting out of sync. So what is the best way to remove an item from a collection.

```
public void RemoveOrderItem(Model.Order currentOrder, int productId)
{

    foreach (var orderItem in currentOrder.OrderItems)
    {
        if (orderItem.Product.Id == productId)
        {
            currentOrder.OrderItems.Remove(orderItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Modifying a collection inside a loop doesn’t work. To work around that, `List` has a few methods that allow “batch” modifications of a collection. In your case, use:

```
currentOrder.OrderItems.RemoveAll(x => x.Product.Id == productId)
```

Comment: thanks conrad, weirdly i can't get the lamda to work. It doesn't recognise the "x.Product.Id" part. Strange cos the following works
var query = from x in currentOrder.OrderItems where x.Product.Id == productId  select x; The collection type is ISet.

Comment: ok, i answered my own question :) I've changed this to List<t>

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify a collection while iterating it. Just use a normal `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: :) this was the best solution for me

Answer (score 3):

By looping this way you can not remove items because its in collection it keeps the track of the stored items.

Easy way to do this :

```
   authorsList.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == productId);
```

or

```
   authorsList = authorsList.Where(x => x.ProductId!= productId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove an item from a collection you are iterating through, you could keep track of the orderItem, then remove it after you finish looping

Answer (score 1):

As you realise you can't remove an item from a collection whilst you are looping over it.  I'm sure someone will be able to provided a neater LINQ solution but the following should get you going initially:

```
public void RemoveOrderItem(Model.Order currentOrder, int productId)
{
    var selectedOrderItem = null;
    foreach (var orderItem in currentOrder.OrderItems)
    {
        if (orderItem.Product.Id == productId)
        {
            selectedOrderItem = orderItem;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(selectedOrderItem != null)
        currentOrder.OrderItems.Remove(selectedOrderItem);
}
```

Comment: Konrad Rudolph has given the LINQ solution

Comment: Note that `List<T>.RemoveAll` is available in .NET 2.0 and is technically not LINQ, though it looks similar. That's a huge plus over LINQ for those poor souls that have to maintain Windows 2000 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

"foreach" provides a "Forward-only read-only" iteration of a collection.

As a workaround, you can copy the reference to another collection and then iterate on the copied collection and remove the items from the original one.