# What is the recommended way for deleting items from a collection?

Tags: powershell, collections

I often need to delete some object from a collection based on some condition and every time I and up with this:

```
Get-SomeCollection | ? { $_.SomeProperty -eq "SomeValue" } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

But this will delete only the first element and then throw an exception "Collection was modified...bla bla...". I get the point of the exception, but **what is the recomended way of doing this?**

I usually use some array `itemsToDelete` and then I iterate again through that array and perform delete operations:

```
$itemsToDelete = @()
Get-SomeCollection | ? { $_.SomeProperty -eq "SomeValue" } | % { $itemsToDelete += $_ }
$itemsToDelete | % { $_.Delete() }
```

I was wondering if this is *good enough* or what is the better way.

Comment: i'm not familiar with powershell. I had a similar question in regards to generics. Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995811/removing-items-from-a-generic-listt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would usually do is to use a filter to actually *filter* items out of a collection. So you don’t modify the original collection but rather simply filter out those you are interested in.

```
Get-SomeCollection | ? { $_.SomeProperty -ne "SomeValue" }
```

If you need to call an operation on the items you want to remove, you can simply create a copy of the filtered collection and enumerate that one instead. Doing that is very simple, as you simply need to enclose the expression in parantheses to make it evaluate before running the enumeration with the command:

```
 (Get-SomeCollection | ? { $_.SomeProperty -eq "SomeValue" }) | % { $_.Delete() }
```

Comment: Well, this is elegant, but not suitable for most of my cases because most of the time I really need to call that delete operation which performs more actions, not only removing from collection (i.e. removing WebPart from the aspx page).

Comment: Wow! I knew that this is hiding from me somewhere!! Thanks for revealing it for me! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the syntax for powershell, but this problem exists with simple foreach statements in .NET

The solution is to iterate backwards in a for loop.

Instead of doing:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   if(condition)
   {
      collection.Remove(item); //exception!
   }
}
```

you do:

```
for(int count = collection.Count - 1; count > 0; count--)
{
   var currentItem = collection[count];
   if(condition)
   {
      collection.RemoveAt(count);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exact problem I have. But my example has relation to the use of pipelines in powershell. I would like to know if there is some solution with the use of original pipeline. Or something more elegant...